# I am looking to hide element on .ready and show them with animation onclick

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking to hide element on .ready and show them with animation onclick. I tried to do it this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bio').hide();
});

$('.anotherdiv).onclick(function() {
  $('.bio').show(2000).animate({ left:'15em' }, 2500);
]);
```

I know I am probably way off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of issues.

- `onclick` should be just `click`
- The click handler needs to be within the `document.ready` block so that it executes once the DOM has been intitialised.
- There's a missing `'` in the `.anotherdiv` selector
- `]` should be `}` in the closing of the click handler

Also note that you should really use CSS to hide element initially so that you don't get a FOUC (flash of unstyled content) as the page loads. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.anotherdiv').click(function() {
    $('.bio').show(2000).animate({
      left: '15em'
    }, 2500);
  });
});
```

```css
.bio { 
  display: none; 
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="anotherdiv">Another DIV</div>
<div class="bio">BIO</div>
```

For future reference you should always check the console when debugging JS code. You would have seen reports of the syntax issues.

Comment: Are you referring to a debugger such as an extension on google chrome

Comment: may i suggest that if the OP has more than one `anotherdiv` on which he wants to click, he should use `.on("click",function() { ` so as to create a single handler for all the elements `anotherdiv`, not one handler for each element, which is the case for `click`

Comment: @MihaiT that would be pretty pointless considering `on('click', fn)` and `click()` have the exact same behaviour.

Comment: @EddieWeldon it's not an extension, the dev console is a standard part of the browser. Either press F12, or right click an element and click 'Inspect'

Comment: as far as i know `.on` click has better performance ( in case of multiple clicked elements ) than `click` . i researched it a while ago and also now i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Comment: That's the delegated handler which is different to what you suggested. The difference is very minor though, unless you have several thousand elements in the DOM

Comment: oh ok. i got a project rejected for this reason ( using click,bind,load instead of on ) and i had only 2 to 4 elements that were used. Well another day another thing learned. thank you for your time and explanation

Comment: @MihaiT whats the different between what you suggested and typing 2nd ('anotherdiv') on a new function

Comment: also why is my question voted down.   I dont know what it entails but is there anyway I can prevent it from happening

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the element hidden (with opacity 0) by default and then just add a click event to show it when document is ready, at which point you can change the opacity to 1?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.anotherdiv').click(function() {
      $('.bio').animate({
         left: '15em',
         opacity: 1 
      }, 2500) 
   });
});
```